# How to codesign and notarize Electron (electron-builder) app on behalf my client?

Tags: macos, electron, electron-builder, codesign, notarize

I'm trying to figure out what I need from my client to codesign and notarize an Electron app on MacOS on behalf of my client.

As far as electron-builder goes I already have that configured to codesign and notarize the app and publish it to github releases.

For the past year I have been doing that on his Mac so I know as far as the code of the app goes everything is correct.

But now I have to codesign, notarize and publish the app to github releases from my own Mac.

Now I know that on his machine electron-builder uses the "Developer ID Application" certificate that is in his keychain and XCode.

From what I understand I need to export that certificate as a .p12 file from his keychain.
Then copy it to my machine and then I should import it into keychain access on my machine?

I tried that but keychain access just says that it cannot import the item.

He is enrolled in the Apple developer program as a business and he added my appleId to their team and assigned the developer role to me.
I am not enrolled in the developer program, I just have a free account. Do I need to be enrolled?

Is this even what I should be doing (importing the .p12 certificate)? If so am I missing a step?